# The "knowledge of knowledge transfer" in technical / non-technical English

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, expressions, idiom-request

I need to know whether there is any technical term to refer to the specific knowledge and ability which is used to transfer the knowledge itself; i.e. I am looking for a (perhaps) technical term that is used as a reference to a successful teacher assuming the fact that they are quite knowledgeable to teach a particular subject matter, however they have the **knowledge of knowledge transfer** too. Is there any technical or non-technical term to refer to this ability? I mean **knowledge of knowledge transfer** in English?

**Added:** 
The former 'knowledge' in "**knowledge** of knowledge transfer", is a sort of **art**. In other words, the **art of knowledge transfer**, which in turn, can be called a knowledge itself. 
I needed to discover whether there is any particular term as a reference to this art or not!
I think there should be something in language teaching terminology, since I heard something once; I cannot remember what that was though!

Comment: "Knowledge of knowledge" is **epistemology**. "Knowledge of knowledge **transfer**" sounds like **teaching** to me. Or **pedagogy** if you're looking for a 50-cent word.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't consider the word *teach*?  It seems odd that that well written question such as yours belongs to someone unfamiliar with the word *teach*. You even use *teach* in the question. Can you add any details to your question on why *teach* hasn't been considered as the answer?  Has teach lost its zing?

Comment: Yes @elliek-dont-support-her. I trued to provide some more details in order to clarify my intention. Please have a look on it and let me know if still there are some ambiguities.

Answer (score 2):

- Knowing how to transfer knowledge
- Knowing how to do knowledge transfer [for example]

> How to Do Knowledge Transfer Effectively So, how does one actually
> transfer knowledge?

Knowledge transfer is an activity. Therefore, how to transfer knowledge means knowing how to do it.

[knowledge transfer](https://helpjuice.com/blog/knowledge-transfer)

Comment: Thank you @Lambie. You seem to be close to the term in my question; however, how can we intensify such a phrase? Perhaps, **"S/he knows well how to effectively transfer knowledge**" or something. That being said, it sounds a little wordy and even stilted somehow! I am wondering how we can moderate it, or rather, how would you phrase it in a more elegant way?

Comment: The term knowledge transfer has been around for ages, and comes from the field of developmental economics. In any case, what I said does not sound stilted.